# how to scroll down with selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to scrape a webpage where in the main page there are 2 scroll bar. I can scroll down main scroll. But how can i scroll left side? i will attach a screenshot, because it is hard to explain it with words.

[image: screenshot]

you can see that there 2 scroll in the picture. i would scroll left side with using selenium webdriver. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can execute JavaScript code that's scrolling the page to specific X, Y and change the X (the Y is height).

Execute it like that:

```
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(X, Y)')
```

Just replace the X and Y for your scrolling values.
Example:

```
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(200, 0)') # It'll scroll to 200 left-position and also scrolling to 0 top-position.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i don't want to scroll page itself, but scroll left side scroll bar. In the photo you can see what i mean by saying left side scroll bar. Any suggestion will appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use this JsExecutor script to scroll to the needed element:

```
driver.execute_script.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```